# Onclick Show / Hide Multiple Divs Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create navigation that shows / hides multiple divs.

**Here is what I need to be able to do**: If a user clicks on any of the "**options**" I need a class named "**selected**" associated to the current selected or chosen item within the nav - this means adding a class to the anchor. You will see there is CSS styling for the class "selected" in my example below.

[View current progress](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/402/)

I am also having trouble trying to have either "option 1" or "option 2" already selected onload so that all of the divs do not appear - Onload I need only one div to appear with the correct "**option**" "**selected**" if that makes sense.

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use data attributes, as just `target` is'nt really valid. I changed it to `data-target` and did:

```
$('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/420/)

`on()` will only work in jQuery 1.7+, so if using an older version of jQuery (your fiddle is), stick with `click()`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your suggested approach, plus a click on the first element to get things started: http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/420/

Comment: @dinjas - Thank you, seems I forgot to save the fiddle and just posted the OP's fiddle (embarrassed) ?

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/415/ . It removes the class "selected" from all `.showSingle` anchors, then adds the class "selected" to the clicked anchor. Also, it handles the onload problem by hiding all the `.targetDiv`s and showing only the first one.

**EDIT:** Should highlight the first option in red on page load too. http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/421/

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** for a non JQuery solution try this:

```
function showHide(element) { 
     var field = document.getElementById(element); 
     if (element) { 
          if (field.style.display == 'none') { 
                field.style.display = 'block'; 
          } else { 
                field.style.display = 'none'; 
          } 
     } 
}
```

That would be your code to show and hide in your JS

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="showSingle" target="1" onClick="showHide(div1);">Option 1</button>
    <button class="showSingle" target="2" onClick="showHide(div2);">Option 2</button>
    <button class="showSingle" target="3" onClick="showHide(div3);">Option 3</button>
    <button class="showSingle" target="4" onClick="showHide(div4);">Option 4</button>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">Lorum Ipsum 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">Lorum Ipsum 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">Lorum Ipsum 4</div>​
```

That should get you started :-)

Totally missed the Jquery my bad

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.showSingle').click(function () {
   $('.targetDiv').hide();
   $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
   $('.showSingle').removeClass('selected')
   $(this).addClass('selected');           
});

var active_link = 1; // Change this value to set the active link
$('a[target='+active_link+']').trigger('click');​
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first trouble you can add the following two lines to your click event:

```
    $(".buttons .selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
```

Or as Irrelepant says (a better way actually):

```
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
```